# Dealing with noise for Frenet-Serret Frames

Tags: noise, frenet-frame

I have a curve and I calculate Frenet-serret frames for each point on the curve. If the curve is smooth (e.g. generated using a formula like a helix) the T-N-B frames are well formed. However, when I use a path recorded using a vision sensor, while tracking a marker, the estimated T-N-B frame is really noisy. How can I deal with such noise while not loosing the desired frames? I sample of the noisy frames can be seen [image: here].

I have tried filtering the frames using `filter` command in MATLAB. The problem is the T-N-B frames loose their properties and are not anymore perpendicular and normalized.

Comment: Has there been any update on this?